# How to change the options of the menuinflater on click the jquery mobile listview item

Tags: android, listview, jquery-mobile, menu

I'm developing my first Android app using jquery mobile and phonegap. I'd like to implement a menuinflater that change the options when I click on the jquery list item. My difficult is to handle the click and pass this one into android menu. Is it possible? I use local storage and JSON parser. However this is part of my code:

```
$(".contentLink").live("click", function() {

    selectedEntry = $(this).data("entryid");
});

function renderEntries(entries) {
    var s = '';

    $.each(entries, function(i, v) {
        s += '<li style="-webkit-border-radius:0px;" class="listheight" data-icon="false"><a href="#contentPage" class="contentLink" data-entryid="'+i+'" style="-webkit-border-radius:0px;"><span class="ui-li-thumb">' + v.image + '</span> <span class="mymargin" style="white-space:normal;">' + v.title + '</span> </a></li>';
    });
    $("#linksList").html(s);
    $("#linksList").listview("refresh");
}
```

and the menuinflater java class is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater infl = getMenuInflater();
    infl.inflate(R.layout.cool_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
            return true;
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.tuxmind.maddom73.ABOUT");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.share:
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            localIntent.setType("*/*");
            localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "Look this");
            localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + TuxMobAppActivity.this.loadUrlTimeoutValue + "\">" + TuxMobAppActivity.this.loadUrlTimeoutValue + "</a>"));
            TuxMobAppActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share using apps-builder.com"));
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```